# Filtering a signal without affecting the square wave

Tags: signals, signals-slots, highpass-filter, data-communication

I have a data signal with a frequency of between 20Khz 50KHz. Every 8ms the sending of data is stopped and a single signal is sent to determine the position of an object. I currently want to filter out the single signal without affecting the data signal. Because the data signal clearly has a higher frequency compared to the single signal, I tried to use a high-pass filter. However, I then drastically influence the data signal. Does anyone know how I can apply this without affecting the data signal.

I have tried using a high pass filter. I have performed simulations using RC and LC filters. However, I affect the data signal.

[Single measurement signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtrKx.jpg)

[Data signal -> frequency 30kHz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9zHR.jpg)